# Is there an efficient way to edit a large number of text-boxes in SSRS(bec. I'm using a slow remote connection)?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I need to simply format a bunch of text boxes, adding boundaries, color etc. It is really slow on my networked connection (using Remote Desktop) and dragging boxes is prohibitively slow.

[image]

I'm thinking I can jump into the RDL code and edit it faster?

Or better yet, I can perhaps grab the RDL, edit  it locally on my machine(I have Vis. Studio 2008 but didn't get SSRS to work locally yet), then I can put it back online(where i'm workin)

Comment: Both things you mention (editing the RDL source, or editing it locally) are options. I don't see the problem/question here?

Comment: @Jeroen - I see your point , yeah I was wondering about how I might edit the RDL source in a pseudo-automatic manner . I think that once I'm better at it, that I can more easily edit the RDL . as of now I'm sort of just poking around with it.. but I am seeing things better, though slowly . thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on a control, then hold down `Control` and click on another - both controls will be highlighted. Do this for as many controls as you want to alter. You can now edit their common properties in one operation.

I guess you could edit the XML directly in an XML editor but I've never done that (other than Visual Studio to fix minor things). The Visual Studio designer is the preferable experience.

It would be better to design the report locally and upload when done.

Comment: Thanks so much Chris, `Control` it is then!!